# How do i make my program ask further questions to the user?

Tags: python, input, python-3.8

i am literally an absolute beginner in programming so i would be very grateful if someone could help me out.
my program looks like this:

```
age = input("Your Age:")
ageNum = int(age)

if ageNum >= 18:
    print("Why do you want to ride the roller coaster")
else:
    print("You are not allowed to ride the roller coaster")
```

it functions exactly the way i want it to but i want add a feature.i want it to ask allow the user to answer 'why do you want to ride the roller coaster'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ask a question for the user to answer, instead of saying

```py
print("Why do you want to ride the roller coaster")
```

(which just displays something on the screen rather than asking the user a question) you can use the built-in `input()` function. So you can replace the line that has

```py
print("Why do you want to ride the roller coaster")
```

with

```py
yourVariableName = input("Why do you want to ride the roller coaster? ")
```

Then you can respond to the user's answer:

```py
print("Your message here")
```